# Firebase SPA rewrite rules not redirecting to index.html

Tags: angularjs, firebase, single-page-application, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I just started to build a **Single-Page App on Firebase Hosting using AngularJS** framework. I have run `firebase init` and chosen to rewrite all urls to `/index.html` as shown below:

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I have my partial view templates stored in the following folders:

```
public/templates/home/dashboard.html
public/templates/courses/default.html
```

My **Angular routings** are working correctly and have my `public/index.html` checks for authorized access, including those partial views, and redirect the user to login view if the user has not been authenticated.

However, when I try to paste the URL of my template HTML files **directly onto the browser address bar**, Firebase **does not redirect** it to `/index.html`:

```
http://localhost:5000/templates/home/dashboard.html
http://localhost:5000/templates/courses/default.html
```

All the above template files are loaded on the browser and viewable by any unauthorized users who know the URLs of these template files. I have tried to add the following rules to my `firebase.json` file but none of them work:

**Test #1:**

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }, 
      {
        "source": "/templates/**/.*",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

**Test #2:**

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }, 
      {
        "source": "/templates{,/**}",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

**NOTE:** I did restart `firebase serve` for every attempt, but I'm not sure if the cache will affect this type of testing. I also don't know how to clear the server cache either.

**My questions are:**

1. What is the correct way to write the url rewrite rule in order to redirect users to `/index.html` when direct accessing to these partial view templates?
2. If there is no way to prevent direct access to partial view templates through the Firebase url rewrite rules, is there any other way that I can prevent this for security purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase hosting will serve static content with priority above dynamic rewrites. [See this hosting order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order).

If you don't want those views accessed directly, you could move them to a cloud function and setting up your hosting to reroute "templates" to serve that cloud function. Then you can configure your cloud function to provide/deny access as needed.

Comment: If I move to cloud function, then what about my Angular **templateUrl**? I tried setting up the **301 redirect** in the `firebase.json`, the first entry from source `/templates/home/dashboard.html` to `/` was working, but the second entry from source `/templates/courses/default.html` to `/course`, which also corresponds to my `$routeProvider` configuration, was not working: Chrome says `You can wait for it to become responsive or exit page.`. Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, that 301 redirects don't seem to work either, it seemed like conflicting with the Angular's `templateUrl` that needs to programmatically perform a **http request** on it.

Answer (score -1):

Use **redirects** instead of **rewrites**

```
"hosting": {
    "redirects": [ {
        "source": "/foo",
        "destination": "/bar",
        "type": 301
    } ]
}
```

Add ** to **source** to append **destination** with additional URL string.

E.g.

```
"hosting": {
    "redirects": [ {
        "source": "/foo**",
        "destination": "/bar",
        "type": 301
    } ]
}
```

Results in `/foo?var=bar` redirecting to `/bar?var=bar`

See [Configure redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) for more info.